# use a custom encoding or add custom characters

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding

Is there anyway i can use some custom encoding or convert some base16 characters (two bytes chars as in japanese SHIFT-JIS) when reading them using binaryreader ? i mean, while reading them, like, if there is a 0x00ff it converts it to "\et", when reading and when writing as well (editing the file, and writing using binarywriter).

Comment: I don't think you need a custom `Encoding` here, just use some kinds of method to convert between the bytes and the characters yourself.

Comment: i've been looking on how to do it, inside of the reading process, but couldn't find anything :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to implement your own Encoding and Decoding, so the problem is related to how you implement them, that depends on your algorithm. The default `Encoding` supports only popular encodings such as `Unicode, BigEndianUnicode, UTF-8, ...`. I suggested that you don't need any kind of custom Encoding, as you can see `Encoding` is just a class with some methods to perform the actual `encoding` and `decoding`, it helps you a lot in handling with the well-known, popular encodings `Unicode`, ... but for your own Encoding, you must implement almost all the core functions like this:

```
public class CustomEncoding : Encoding
{
    //NOTE: There are some abstract members requiring you to implement or declare in this derived class.
    public override byte[] GetBytes(string s)
    {
        //Your code goes here            
    }
    public override string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        //Your code goes here
    }
    //And many other virtual (overridable) methods which you can override to implement your custom Encoding fully
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, so the 'public override string GetString(byte[] bytes)' is for the custom encoding, where my code would be to replace the bytes with the appropriate string, right ? is so, why would i need an 'override byte[]' ?

Comment: @Omarrrio `GetString` is used to decode (convert from bytes to string) while `GetBytes` is used to encode (convert from string to bytes).