# Using Lambda OrderBy Comparer to give weight to a specific string value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

The title is perhaps a little confusing (please change if it is)

I have a list of objects, example is:

```
public class MyObj{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string MyType {get;set;}
}
```

Let's say I have a `List<MyObj>` that contains 4 elements.

The types on each of these are:

```
myObj1.MyType = "ABC";
myObj2.MyType = "7551";
myObj3.MyType = "AAABB";
myObj3.MyType = "CDE";
```

I would like to, if possible, order this list so that `"ABC"` has the most weight and comes first. The rest of the list can be sorted alphabetically.

I'm in .Net 4.5 so can use the `Comparer<>.Create()` - i just have no idea how to do what I need to do.

Comment: Might you want to create your own custom encoding - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386062/use-a-custom-encoding-or-add-custom-characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess something like this would work (and without the need for Comparers)

```
myList.OrderByDescending(o=>o.MyType == "ABC").ThenBy(o=>o.MyType);
```

Basically, it orders the list by whether it is ABC or not (and floats them to the top), then the remainder is ordered normally.

The reason the first `OrderBy` clause is Descending is that false comes before true, so in order to float the ABCs to the top, it needs to sort in reverse.

Comment: Oh man! I clearly overthought this entire process! Many thanks, this works perfectly.